# TextView gravity="top" but changing font size dynamically doesn't keep text align to the top

Tags: layout, text, textview, alignment, font-size

I have an app that needs to dynamically align text views over certain locations on an image.  The image is scaled to fit the view.  Text entries are added by the user.  I'm using a RelativeLayout and margins to properly position the text.  All is good.

When the user rotates the screen, I save the text locations and bitmap using onRetainNonConfigurationInstance().  When the view is recreated, I add the views back into the RelativeLayout.  Now, because the view is a different size, the scale of the image is different.  To keep the text boxes in the same location, I have to account for that.  I have all that code working except for one issue....

If I create a TextView and set the fontSize to a small size (e.g. <11px), the top of the text box is positioned where I want it to be but the text is aligned with a baseline as if it were 11px font.  I don't know the scale factor in the onCreate method so I can't change the font size until after onMeasure and onLayout are called.  I've tried forceLayout() and requestLayout() but nothing seems to fix the alignment problem.

Here is the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="0dp"
>
    <com.xyx.ScalableLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:gravity="top"
    >
        <com.xyx.ScaledImageView
            android:id="@+id/formView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="0dp"
        />
    <com.xyx.ScalableLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

A textView is added with the following code:

```
textView = new TextView(getContext());
textView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
textView.setSingleLine();
textView.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
textView.setClickable(false);
textView.setGravity(Gravity.TOP);
textView.setText(entry.mText);
float fontSize = mImageView.mapSizeToView(entry.mPointSize);
textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PT, fontSize);
params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
        ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
        ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.leftMargin = Math.round(viewLoc.x);
params.topMargin = Math.round(viewLoc.y);
addView(textView, params);
```

When ScaledImageView gets an onSizeChanged() callback, it sets the scale value and updates the font size and location of TextViews with the following code:

```
float fontSize = mImageView.mapSizeToView(entry.mPointSize);
textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PT, fontSize);
PointF viewLoc = computeTopLeft(entry, entry.mTextView.getPaint());
params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) textView.getLayoutParams();
params.leftMargin = Math.round(viewLoc.x);
params.topMargin = Math.round(viewLoc.y);
textView.setLayoutParams(params);
textView.forceLayout();
```

And finally, I do a 
    requestLayout() on the ScalableLayout

I know that's a lot of code but my problem is this.  If I know the proper scale factor (used in mapSizeToView()) when I am creating the TextView and adding it to the screen everything works fine.  If the value is incorrect, then nothing I can find will do a full recalculate that will get the TextView to be the same as if it were created with that font size.  I believe it is tied to Android Layout structure which I generally understand.  However, I don't understand why I can't get it to recompute from scratch (short of tearing down all the views and recreating them).